# Neo4j using Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, neo4j

Is there a good tutorial explaining how to use Neo4j in Rails and get it setup on Heroku.

I am having trouble understanding how I am suppose to setup Neo4j and Rails locally for testing before I deploy on Heroku. On my local machine what exactly am I suppose to do in Rails to setup Neo4j given that Neo4j is an embedded Java database but Rails is Ruby based. More precisely, where in rails do I give the command "run the Java virtual machine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are right. For embedded Rails setup, this is not the right place. How about doing Amazon instead for that scenario? Otherwise, try https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography which works great on Heroku?